# Proguard app Execution ERROR

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, dexguard

When I'm not using proguard, it is working perfectly fine. But, when I try to use dexguard or proguard, it's not working. But I can make apk file.

Surprise thing is I try options and it doesn't optimize my files, same Error happened.

Error is :

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: failed resolution of ~~
    ~~~~~~
    ~~~~~~~
```

So I tried to debugg, and I found that app stopped at below code segment.

```
    private Class library = null;
    this.library = new Class (this)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this code does? Perhaps there is a way to refactor this. Also, can you post a larger piece of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
    -dontwarn com.facebook.**
```

in your proguard file. Replace facebook with your library name in which you are getting error.